# add elements in the same array of service from two different components - angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a web app built using angular with typescript for frontend and I wanna populate an array from a service with data from two different components and I am using localStorage in the service to keep the data at refresh of the page.

So far I did this:
In service.ts I have an Array of objects and some function to work with it:

```
items: Array<ProductDTO> = new Array<ProductDTO>();
addToCart(product: ProductDTO) {
    this.items.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(this.items));  
  }

  getItems() {
    this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    return this.items;
  }
```

addToCart function populates the array and uses localStorage so the data won't get lost at refresh and getItems returns the array.

Then in one of the components I have all the products displayed and when I click a button I can add it to the cart and it should populate this variable from the service:

```
 addToCard(product: ProductDTO) {
    var index = this.cart.items.indexOf(product);
    if (index == -1) {
      product["quantity"] = 1;
      this.cart.addToCart(product);
    } 
    else if (index != -1) 
      this.cart.items[index]["quantity"]++;
  }
```

Also, in other component, which shows the details of the product based on the product you clicked on and I have the same addToCart function which should do the same as the one above, but here I am adding the data regarding the current product:

```
  public products: Array<ProductDTO> = new Array<ProductDTO>();
  addToCard() {
    var index = this.cart.items.indexOf(this.product);
    if (index == -1) {
      this.product["quantity"] = 1;
      this.cart.addToCart(this.product);
    }

    else if (index != -1) 
      this.cart.items[index]["quantity"]++;
  }
```

So, when adding a product from one of the two components it should increase the quantity value if the product it's already present in the array of objects. The issue I am facing is that if I add the same product multiple times from one component in one session it works fine, it increments the quantity value:

> 0: category: null color: "rosu" description: "Trandafir rosu" id: "10"
> name: "Trandafir rosu" picture:
> "https://i.ibb.co/3csBF4H/firtrandafir.png" price: 10 quantity: 4
> stock: 299

but when I add one product from a component and the same product from the other component or if I add the product from the first component, then navigate to other component and then come back to the component and try to add the same item it creates two records in the array, each with qauntity = 1:

> 0: category: null color: "rosu" description: "Trandafir rosu" id: "10"
> name: "Trandafir rosu" picture:
> "https://i.ibb.co/3csBF4H/firtrandafir.png" price: 10 quantity: 1
> stock: 299

> 1: category: null color: "rosu" description: "Trandafir rosu" id: "10" name: "Trandafir rosu" picture:
> "https://i.ibb.co/3csBF4H/firtrandafir.png" price: 10 quantity: 1
> stock: 299

Do you have any idea what should I do in order to increase the quantity no matter the component I add the product from?

Comment: Try to get existing product using id `var index = this.cart.items.indexOf(product.id);` before adding to cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to get the index is **wrong**, you sould ask about a property of an object, not simple is the product is equal to the other. I suppose the "id" is uniq, so replace your `this.cart.items.indexOf(...)` by

```
var index = this.cart.items.findIndex(x=>x.id==this.product.id)
```